# @OneToMany Association of Entities with a composite key in the child entity in hibernate

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jboss

Parent Entity for TOUR Table(TOUR_ID is the primary key)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOUR")
public class TourEO implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TOUR_ID")
    private long tourId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tourEO", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private List<TourLocaleEO> tourLocale = new ArrayList<TourLocaleEO>();
    ...
}
```

Creating embeddable composite key for table

```
@Embeddable
public class TourLocalePK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TOUR_ID")
    private TourEO tourEO;

    @Column(name = "LOCALE")
    private String locale;
    ...
}
```

Child entity for TOUR_LOCALE table(TOUR_ID, and LOCALE forms the composite key and note that TOUR_ID is a foreign key from parent)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOUR_LOCALE")
public class TourLocaleEO implements Serializable {
        @EmbeddedId
        private TourLocalePK tourLocalePK;
        ...
}
```

With this, jboss server fails to start. I can't share the log(but nothing much relevant error I saw)

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: *I can't share the log*--if you have sensitive info there, post only relevant parts

Comment: Unable to fetch csf bean cache capacity from *Config
I am not quite sure whether this could be helpful. But this is difference when I have associations and when I don't ahve

Comment: http://kruders.com/hibernate/foreign-key-constraint-to-a-composite-primary-key-in-hibernate/
I tried this too